# Обновление схемы БД у пользователей

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sqlite, installshield

Каким образом средствами Installshield можно организовать обновление схемы БД на клиенте. Используемая БД -SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Installshield` - это просто система для создания инсталяторов. Ей нет никакого дела до баз данных, схем или чего либо еще, ее задача - устанавливать.

В идеале, если в проекте предполагаются обновления схем, то как правило используется `EF` - `Code First` и`Migration`.

Подробный гайд [тут](http://hintdesk.com/sqlite-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-migration/)

Если же вы об этом не позаботились, то вам придется писать миграции вручную. Это так же можно сделать средствами EF, а так же сторонними инструментами, например с помощью [FluentMigrator](https://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/easy-database-migrations-with-c-and-fluentmigrator/)

Comment: InstallShield выполняет скрипты над бд если версия бд меньше версии скрипта, в случае использования MS SQLServer, который на данный момент используется в моем приложении. Но встала необходимость перейти на встроенную СУБД и как теперь выполнять обновление схем пока что еще не разобрался. Приложение на Net 3.5, поэтому использование EF6 невозможно.